# Which signal can tell me unchecked checkbox?

Tags: qt, qt4, signals-slots, qcheckbox

Suppose I have set of `QCheckBoxes`, I set some of them. I need to understand when I uncheck them, but I don't know which `signal` can help me?
The following code tell me checked:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.checkBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("isChecked()")), lambda: self.interfaceCodesConstructor.setFilterDict(self,"name",self.lineEdit.text()))
```

and I `connect` a `lambda function`.

**My question** is, which `signal` can  tell me `checkbox` is unchecked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [`void QCheckBox::stateChanged ( int state ) [signal]`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcheckbox.html#stateChanged), from description :

This signal is emitted whenever the check box's state changes, i.e. whenever the user checks or unchecks it.
state contains the check box's new Qt::CheckState.

So after you connect it to slot, just check, if state variable equals `Qt::Checked` and process your slot, else - return.